# Accessing a variable in a void from main

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, function

My Form1_Load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread Usern = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Username));
    Usern.Start();
}
```

And my Username function:

```
public static void Username()
{
    try
    {
        string user = Environment.UserName;
        MessageBox.Show(user.ToString());
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    { 
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Tostring()); 
    }
}
```

Anyone know how I would call "user" used in the function above ^ inside of Form_Load event? I've tried changing the function return type to string but it says it's an invalid change.
I know that I could just copy and paste the code from the function into form_load event but it has to be in the function.

Thank you guys in advance and sorry for such a "stupid question" as I didn't find anything related of my problem on SO.

Comment: Why would you need to call this `Username` method in another thread? Doesn't makes sense for me.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: This is just a snippet of the full code. I'm trying to grab all sorts of info of the PC and then post it back on the server for analytics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably make `user` an *instance* variable instead of a local variable - in other words, declare it in your class:

```
private string user;
```

then in `Username()` (which should be renamed to `DetectUserName` or something similar) you would just have:

```
user = Environment.UserName;
```

Your method should be an instance method though, so that it's associated with an instance of the class - remove the `static` keyword from the method declaration.

It's not at all clear why you want to do this in a different thread though...

Comment: Thank you this worked the way I wanted it to :) I collect all kinds of information and then post it all back on the server in one piece. This was just a snippet of a code.

Comment: @WilliamJ: You may want to encapsulate all that information in a single variable then, of some new type. That would be cleaner than having a bunch of variables in your form, if that's what you're doing now. Also consider using async/await if you can... It may well make things cleaner.